# I apply the sum-to-product identity for $\sin$, but my result differs from the textbook's

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I don't understand the last transformation here:

$$\sin x - \cos 3x = 0\iff \sin x -\sin\left(\frac\pi2 - 3x\right) =0\iff 2\sin\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)\cos\left(2x-\frac\pi4\right)=0$$

When I apply the sum-to-product identity for $\sin(x)-\sin(y)$, I get the opposite set of arguments in the brackets:

$$2\sin\left(2x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)$$

I'm probably missing some trivial point (being tired a bit).

---

The textbook's solution in full is:

[image]

P.S. Even if we go with the textbook's result, the periodicity for the second $x$ should be simply $n\pi$, not $\frac{n\pi}{2}$, methinks.

Comment: You can tell that there's an error in the book's solution, since $x=\pi/4$ does not satisfy the original equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\sin { a-\sin { b } =2\sin { \frac { a-b }{ 2 } \cos { \frac { a+b }{ 2 }  }  }  } $$

Comment: This is the identity I had applied in the first place, and got $\left(2x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ for the first bracket, which is at odds with the textbook's result.

Comment: it seems there is typo in your textbook

Comment: A typo? Okay, I'll notify the author. I just wasn't sure.